# Simple CSS keyframe animation not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am making a simple example of CSS animation but it does not run. Pl help someone!

```html
<html>
<head>

<style>

.dot{
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
    animation: pulse 1s infinite;

}

@keyframes  pulse{
 0% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0em #c0392b;}
 25% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em #c0392b;}
 50% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em #c0392b;}
 75% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em #c0392b;}
 100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15em #c0392b;}
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<span class="dot"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `display: inline-block;` to your span and you are good to go

```
.dot{
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
    animation: pulse 1s infinite;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`span` is an `inline element` so you have to add `display:inline-block` to the `.dot` class to make it work.

> Below is the working example-

```html
<html>
<head>

<style>

.dot{
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 10px;
    animation: pulse 1s infinite;
    display:inline-block;

}

@keyframes  pulse{
 0% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0em #c0392b;}
 25% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em #c0392b;}
 50% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em #c0392b;}
 75% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25em #c0392b;}
 100% {box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.15em #c0392b;}
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<span class="dot"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `default display of span is inline`, so as suggested as soon as you change it `display` to `block or inline-block` it show your animation.

```
span{
display:inline;/*Default*/
} 

.dot{
...........
...........
...........
display:block;/*or inline-block*/
}
```